# how should I remove krb5libs in kerberos?

Tags: command-line, centos, kerberos

I am not able to remove krb5libs

I have the following error while removing krb5lib.

```
yum remove krb5-libs

Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some packages may be in an incomplete state and need cleanup.

The article
[Fixing yum incomplete transactions](https://www.frangarcia.me/posts/fixing-yum-incomplete-transactions/)
offers this script:

```
package-cleanup --dupes | grep -v Loaded | awk 'NR % 2 == 0' | xargs -n1 rpm -e --nodeps --justdb --noscripts
yum update
yum-complete-transaction
yum -y reinstall kernel
```

The explanation is that the
first command gets a list of duplicate RPMs and, with the `awk` command get one
out of each two lines. This is piped to rpm to mark each RPM as removed without
running its removal script or actually removing the files from disk.